# What is the difference between REN and RENAME?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, rename, duplicate

I typed `help` into cmd and the following lines were part of the output:

```
REN            Renames a file or files.
RENAME         Renames a file or files.
```

Next I typed `help ren` and `help rename` and got the same outputs:

```
C:\Users\Rahul>help ren
Renames a file or files.

RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.

Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file.

C:\Users\Rahul>help rename
Renames a file or files.

RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.

Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file.
```

Why did Microsoft bother to make two identical commands?

Comment: Probably for the same reason many command line tools support both long and short option names. You’re faster when you know what you’re doing.

Comment: Just like `cd`/`chdir`, `rd`/`rmdir` and `del`/`erase`.

Comment: ... and `md`/`mkdir` as well :P

Comment: Take a look at the similar post [What is the difference between MD and MKDIR batch command? \[Stack Overflow\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32370254)…

Answer (score 3):

> REN and RENAME are synonyms. You may use either one. If you don't specify any arguments, REN will display its command dialog

Sources:

http://jpsoft.com/help/ren.htm
http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html

Answer (score 2):

Type either

```
ren /?
```

or

```
rename /?
```

and one is an abbrievation of the other.

`MkDir`/`MD`, `ChDir`/`CD` and `RmDir`/`RD` are the other commands with abbrievations

Comment: …as well as `erase` and `del`…